# Is it possible to stationarize sinusoidal pattern?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, python, arima

I have a multi-frequency cosines data and want to predict next points of it, so I applied `arima` model which assumes that the data should be stationary. I tried to stationarize the data with log-transformation without differencing (because there is no trend) but there is still a variation in the variance along the data.

What should I do to turn it to stationary? Or this question is even ill-posed? because I read that stationarity is not a property of such data with cosines!

What I mean by cosines is something like the image below:

[image]

Comment: If it is sinusoidal, then how can the data have multiple-frequency components? Sinusoidal means there is only one frequency.

Comment: @Alex sorry, I have to edit that and delete 'sinusoidal'.

Comment: Please, then, clarify what you mean by "sinusoidal pattern" and "cosines data."

Comment: @whuber I edited the question and added a photo, is it okay now?

Comment: Your data certainly has 2 or 3 dominant frequencies. What you see in the plot is a beat pattern. You can generate this by adding three cosine or sinusoidal waves with different frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

In the original version of this post, it was mentioned that there are multiple frequency components in the signal. I'm assuming this means that there are multiple seasonalities present in the time series.

If that is indeed the case, then ARIMA won't work, as in practice an ARIMA model can handle at most one seasonality (using seasonal ARIMA).

You might want to use the TBATS method from Hyndman's Forecast library instead.

Or you might be able to use Facebook' Prophet library - which is very intuitive and easy to use - but it won't be possible unless your time stamps are formatted to a very specific calendar type of data. (If not then just stick with TBATS).

Comment: Thank you, but do you mean that the picture added in my question has multiple seasonalities?